# how to call function parent to child which is inside model class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this model class which has a refresh method,

```
class Model{
  ...
   void refresh(){}
}
```

I'm calling this method from Parent widget like this,

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Parent State createState() => _Parent State();
}

class _Parent State extends State<Parent >
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final Model model = Model();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
    children:[
       Child(model: model),
       IconButton(onPressed:model.refresh)
           ]
        );
   }

}
```

this is child widget,

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final Model model;

  const Child({
    Key? key,
    required this.model,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {}
```

so what I want is to override that method in here and call that whenever it's called from parent.

In short what I need is a callback from parent to child which need to be inside the `Model` class. So How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but I guess you can add `Function callback;` to your model class, assign some function to it in child widget and call it like `callback();` in your `refresh` method body.

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082460/how-to-change-state-of-page-builded-with-navigator/71082987#71082987

Comment: @SandeepSingh I know this can be done with the state management but I'm implementing a plugin and I need to give user a controller from where they can interact

Comment: Your code is also confusing. You have a _ParentState but also _ChildState, neither of them have a connection between. Please share what you want more clearly.

Comment: @salihgueler that was written by mistake I have edited it now

Comment: @obywan I have edited the code if you have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I knew I can do it with state management but using another library was not a option and I totally forgot about the change notifier so I implemented like this,

```
class Model extends ChangeNotifier{

void refresh(){
  notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget{
final Model model
Child(this.model);
...
 @override
 initState(){
 model.addListener((){});
  }
}
```

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget{

final Model model = Model();
...
  Child(model),
  SomeWidget(
    onTap:(){
    model.refresh();
}
  ),
}
```